# Matlab - for loop: create two threads and join them each n iterations

Tags: multithreading, matlab

Each n steps of a for-loop I need to perform a time consuming operation that I will only need n iterations later (for the next time I call this time consuming operation) - still I need results of iteration i-1 to start the computation.

I believe I could benefit from multithreading - with only 2 threads. At i: 
(1st thread): keep running the main loop until it reaches i + n and wait for the 2nd thread to be finished.
(2nd) do the time consuming operation.

Anyway to implement that in Matlab??

```
for i=1:1:N
  y(i) = g(y(i-1), x(i-1));

  if(mod(i, n) == 1)
    x(i) = f(x(i-n), y(i-1)); %Time consuming
  else
    x(i) = x(i-1);
  end
end
```

Thanks!

Comment: That is not how multi treading works.

Comment: parallel-processing then?

Answer (score 1):

You can separate the script into two parts:
1. First loop to compute y array
2. Second loop to compute the x array

You can use the parallel computing toolbox to speed up the second loop. e.g. parfor

Comment: I have edited my code: computation of y(i) requires the last updated x, so I can't separate them in two loops as you mentioned. Thanks anyway

Comment: In this case, even you can implement it parallel, you won't see much change in terms of computational speed. The computation of x(i) still limit your overall computational speed. Due to the dependency, I don't think it can be efficiently implemented parallel.